# Disable windows key of my desktop but not in the form C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, shortcut, guacamole

I try to do a remote desktop app client based in guacamole with HTML5 in a web browser, so I try to disable the windows key in my windows but not in my form, and I don't know how to do that, this is my code:

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
        /* Code to Disable WinKey, Alt+Tab, Ctrl+Esc Starts Here */

        // Structure contain information about low-level keyboard input event 
        private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public Keys key;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public IntPtr extra;
        }


        //System level functions to be used for hook and unhook keyboard input  
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);
        //Declaring Global objects     
        private IntPtr ptrHook;
        private LowLevelKeyboardProc objKeyboardProcess;

        private IntPtr captureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
        {
            
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));

                // Disabling Windows keys 
                
                if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin)
                {
                    return (IntPtr)1; // if 0 is returned then All the above keys will be enabled

                
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
        }

        bool HasAltModifier(int flags)
        {
            return (flags & 0x20) == 0x20;
        }

        /* Code to Disable WinKey, Alt+Tab, Ctrl+Esc Ends Here */
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            ProcessModule objCurrentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
            objKeyboardProcess = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(captureKey);
            ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, objKeyboardProcess, GetModuleHandle(objCurrentModule.ModuleName), 0);

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

this works great, the windows key is disabled but it's disabled too in the form.
so, how could I do to disable the windows key of my windows and not in my form? (because I need the windows key to open the shortcut in the remote).

Comment: You've intercepted the key in your hook. You form can do something with the key now.

Comment: yes i know, but how i send to the form the windows key, because if i send the key press doesnt work, thanks

Comment: Your form already has the key! In your `captureKey` function, do whatever it is you want the form to do.

Comment: In `captureKey()`, check [GetForegroundWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) to see if your form is the active one?